# How to play this video : BigBuckBunny as H264 Adaptive Bitrate MP4 Set 720p

Tags: c#, console, azure-media-services

Currently, I uploaded video through "AESDynamicEncryptionAndKeyDeliverySvc" project.
It is uploaded successfully and listed in Content at my Azure portal as "BigBuckBunny as H264 Adaptive Bitrate MP4 Set 720p". 
Its Encryption is coming as "Custom (customer configures more than one policies through APIs)"

One more content uploaded as "BigBuckBunny".
Its Encryption is coming as "Unsupported".

I published Second content also.

But for first content "BigBuckBunny as H264 Adaptive Bitrate MP4 Set 720p" play option is disable where as for second option "BigBuckBunny" play option is enable.

How to play this videos?

Both contents have publish url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why in portal shows "Custom (customer configures more than one policies through APIs)" is because you have more than one policy configured on your asset (you probably configured it through some other way before).

In order to enable Dynamic Encryption, please double check whether you have at least 1 reserved Streaming RU enabled. If so, you could either try to playback your content via portal, or here is a previewed player we will give for free: http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/azuremediaplayer.html. You can paste in your AES URL and token (if you configured token authentication).

Please let me know if you have more questions: you can email me directly at yanmf@microsoft.com. Meanwhile, if you could paste your publish URL here, i could help you take a quick look also.

Thanks,
Mingfei Yan

Comment: Thank you ma'am, I will try this and let you know